# Symmetries in Dynkin diagrams and the McKay correspondence

Tags: dynkin-diagrams

The McKay correspondence establishes a connection between the set of finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and the set of affine Dynkin diagrams.

Some of these diagrams are very symmetric; for instance, the group of graph automorphisms of the Dynkin diagram $D_4$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$.

How does the existence of graph automorphisms on the Dynkin side of the correspondence translate (if it does) to a representation theoretic statement about the corresponding subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$?

Comment: Just to clarify, it is possibly just a typo, but the automorphism group of the $D_4$ diagram is $S_3$, not $S_4$.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the _affine_ Dynkin diagram $D_4$, not the usual one. I should probably refer to it as $\tilde{D}_4$ though...

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't. It might imply something about the corresponding du Val singularity, though.